# multiple shared_ptr that point to the same object

Tags: c++, smart-pointers

Just for studying purpose I'm coding binary search tree rotation now.
I normally use `std::unique_ptr` but I used `std::shared_ptr` this time

This works correctly:

```
// Node implementation
template <Containable T = int> struct Node {
  T key_ = T{};
  bool black_ = false; // red-black tree
  std::shared_ptr<Node> left_;
  std::shared_ptr<Node> right_;
};

// this is a protected member function of red-black tree class
// xp is parent node of x
void left_rotate(Node *xp, Node* x) {
    assert(x);
    auto y = x->right_;
    x->right_ = y->left_;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> x_ptr;
    if (!xp) {
      x_ptr = root_;
      root_ = y;
    } else if (x == xp->left_.get()) {
      x_ptr = xp->left_;
      xp->left_ = y;
    } else {
      x_ptr = xp->right_;
      xp->right_ = y;
    }
    y->left_ = x_ptr;
  }
```

This crashes:

```
void left_rotate(Node *xp, Node* x) {
    assert(x);
    auto y = x->right_;
    x->right_ = y->left_;
    std::shared_ptr<Node> x_ptr(x);
    if (!xp) {
      root_ = y;
    } else if (x == xp->left_.get()) {
      xp->left_ = y;
    } else {
      xp->right_ = y;
    }
    y->left_ = x_ptr;
  }
```

cppreference says: [Link](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

> `std::shared_ptr` is a smart pointer that retains shared ownership of an object through a pointer. Several shared_ptr objects may own the same object. The object is destroyed and its memory deallocated when either of the following happens:
>
> - the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is destroyed;
> - the last remaining shared_ptr owning the object is assigned another pointer via operator= or reset().

To avoid destroying the node pointed to by `x` before assigning, I created another `std::shared_ptr<Node>` that owns `*x`, but in the second implementation, the node object pointed by `x` is already destroyed before `y->left_ = x_ptr` is called. The node object is actually destroyed when one of `root_ = y`, `xp->left_ = y` and `xp->right_ = y` is called.

There are clearly multiple `std::shared_ptr` objects that own the same node object. `root_`, `xp->left_` or `xp->right_` is clearly NOT the last remaining `std::shared_ptr` owning the object. Why this happens?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. Generally if you have both a naked pointer and a shared pointer to the same thing, you are up to some troubles. `std::shared_ptr<Node> x_ptr(x);` **will** lead to crashes if there is another shared pointer that points to the same node `x` does.

Comment: If you are adopting (taking ownership with `std::shared_ptr`) an already created pointer that's usually a warning flag regarding ownership.  It's not always wrong but a reason for concern and further investigation.  I would expect to see [std::make_shared](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) and possibly the copying of `std::shared_ptr`.

Comment: @RichardCritten ```std::make_shared``` has no constructor that accepts raw pointer. I learned that assignment and copying is ok and creating another ```std::shared_pointer``` with raw pointer as parameter is not okay by experiment, but I want to know why

Comment: `std::shared_pointer with raw pointer as parameter is not okay by experiment` it is ok if the raw pointer has ownership over the object it is pointing to, and if you can take the ownership await at that point.

Comment: If you take ownership of a raw pointer with 2 different `std::shared_ptr`s this will create 2 independent owners (and control blocks / reference counters) and as there is no link between the 2 different `std::shared_ptr`s, this will lead to double-delete's etc.  The correct way is to take ownership with is with 1 `std::shared_ptr` and then copy the `std::shared_ptr`.  This will lead to 2 `std::shared_ptr`s sharing the control block and correctly reference counting the managed raw pointer.  BUT stop taking ownership of raw pointers and use `std::make_shared` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
void left_rotate(Node *xp, Node* x) {
    ...
    std::shared_ptr<Node> x_ptr(x);
    ...
```

When you create the `shared_ptr` it takes over ownership of `x`. The problem here is that it is not yours to give. Someone else, another `shared_ptr`, already has ownership of the pointer. So some of the operations you do before `y->left = xptr` will assign a new value to the `shared_ptr` owning `x` and that deletes the `x`.

The problem is that you use raw pointers as arguments. Whenever you extract the pointer from a `shared_ptr` be very careful about the lifetime of the object. The extracted raw pointer does not keep the object alive. Something that becomes exceedingly difficult to reason about with function calls. Easy to mess up as you experienced.

It's easily avoided by passing `shared_ptr` as arguments because they will keep your objects alive:

```
void left_rotate(std::shared_ptr<NodeY> xp, std::shared_ptr<Node> x) {
```

PS: I hope your `root_` is a `shared_ptr` too.